# Different functions with labels in java depending on position, in front/behind ex: for

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Right I wanted to know why? I observe that depending on where you put the label, as seen in the example below, the outcome of the for loop is different and I wanted to know why?

```
stop1: for(int x = 0; x<5;x++) {
       for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
           if (y == 2) break stop1;
           System.out.println("X and/run1 Y:" + x +"  "+ y);
           System.out.println();
       }
   }

       for(int x = 0; x<5;x++)
           stop2:{ 
               for (int y = 0; y<5; y++){
                   if(y==2) break stop2;
                   System.out.println("X and/run2 Y:" + x +"  "+ y);
                   System.out.println();
               }
           }
```

I found this statement in a Java book but I don't quite get what it's saying really:

In the program, both nested loops are the same except for one point. In the first set, the label precedes the outer for loop. In this case when break executes, it transfers control to the end of the entire for block, skipping the rest of the for loop's iterations. In the second set, the label precedes the outer for's opening curly brace. Thus when break (stop2) executes, control is transferred to the end of the outer for's block, causing the next iteration to occur.

Soz for long text. Help would be appreciated.
Btw outcome of code is following

```
X and/run1 Y:0  0

X and/run1 Y:0  1

X and/run2 Y:0  0

X and/run2 Y:0  1

X and/run2 Y:1  0

X and/run2 Y:1  1

X and/run2 Y:2  0

X and/run2 Y:2  1

X and/run2 Y:3  0

X and/run2 Y:3  1

X and/run2 Y:4  0

X and/run2 Y:4  1
```

Edit: It seems like one is a break and the other a continue or one breaks two fors and the other only one?

Comment: `stop1` breaks the outer loop, `stop2` breaks the inner loop. What output would you expect?

Answer (score 0):

> In the program, both nested loops are the same except for one point. In the first set, the label precedes the outer for loop. In this case when break executes, it transfers control to the end of the entire for block, skipping the rest of the for loop's iterations. In the second set, the label precedes the outer for's opening curly brace. Thus when break (stop2) executes, control is transferred to the end of the outer for's block, causing the next iteration to occur.

This is a perfectly normal behaviour, your code is working 100% fine. Here's what happens when you apply a break statement on a label:

Most times, labels are placed directly in front of loop bodies like this:

```
motherLoop:
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
       //some code
            }
```

Normally, applying a break statement to this label as in `break motherLoop` practically breaks (terminates) the entire loop and flow continues from the part of your code immediately after the loop. For example:

```
motherLoop:
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     if(i == 2){
       break motherLoop;
          }
       System.out.println("Hey");
          }

    System.out.println("I'm done with the loop");
```

The code above produces this output:

> Hey
>
> Hey
>
> I'm done with the loop

This works like the traditional break statement. The real application of this concept comes out when you have multiple loops. Now, back to your question:

```
for(int x = 0; x<5;x++)
       stop2:{ 
           for (int y = 0; y<5; y++){
               if(y==2) break stop2;
               System.out.println("X and/run2 Y:" + x +"  "+ y);
               System.out.println();
           }
       }
```

In the code above, when `y == 2`, the innermost loop (since it's the loop immediately preceded by the label) is broken. **Note that this does not affect the outermost loop in any way**. The flow just continues from the next iteration of the outermost loop.

Now, this one:

```
stop1: for(int x = 0; x<5;x++) {
       for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
           if (y == 2) break stop1;
           System.out.println("X and/run1 Y:" + x +"  "+ y);
           System.out.println();
       }
   }
```

When `y == 2`, the outermost loop (since that's the loop immediately preceded by the label) is broken. This affects all the contents of the outermost loop >> included the inner loop.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Comment: In the 3rd example, would placing stop2 before and after the '{' have the same effect. I though the break+label worked like the goto from assembly where it is a simple jump to line x. If I understand what you are saying, the break+label works in a way where it breaks the loop immediately after the label (label: for), in this case it would break the for as it is preceded by the label. My confusion was due to the fact that I believed that the break worked as a "jump to line" where it could technically be used anywhere inside the loop to jump from line x to line y. THX for the help

Comment: Labels compulsorily have to be before loop declarations, therefore putting 'stop2' after the `{` would fault that purpose and would not work.

Comment: Yeah! It's different in Java. They are generally used to manipulate loops. Also note that you can use a `continue` keyword with labels too. Merry coding! ;-)

Comment: Also, you can mark this answer as the correct answer if it helped.